# shift the binding of block with args

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm learning ruby by writing a simple DSL. The DSL is used to support Event Sourcing block.

```
class Coupon
    include AggregateRoot

    attr_reader :status

    on :CouponApprovedEvent do |event|
        #want to update @status of Coupon instance
        #but the binding is with Coupon class
        @status = 'APPROVED' 
    end

    #other instance methods of Coupon 
end
```

The "on" methods of Coupon maps block to the given event, which is used to reconstitute the aggregate. It is defined in module AggregateRoot:

```
module AggregateRoot

    attr_reader :events

    def handle event
        operation = self.class.event_handlers[event.class.name.to_sym]
        operation.call event
    end

    def self.included(clazz)
        clazz.class_eval do
            @event_handlers = {}

            def self.on event_clazz, &operation
                @event_handlers[event_clazz] = operation
            end

            def self.event_handlers
                @event_handlers
            end
        end
   end
end
```

But the following test fails due to the block is binded with Coupon class, therefore it updates Coupon class.status instead of Coupon instance.status.

```
class CouponTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
    def setup
       @id = 1
       @ar = Coupon.new(@id)
    end

    def test_reconsititute_aggregate_root
       @ar.handle(CouponApprovedEvent.new(@id))
       assert @ar.approved?
    end
end
```

So I changed the block call like this to shift the binding:

```
module AggregateRoot

    def handle event
        operation = self.class.event_handlers[event.class.name.to_sym]
        instance_eval(&operation)
    end
end
```

The test passes in this case, but I found the |event| argument is lost(the coupon instance is passed instead).

Is there a way to shift the binding of the block with args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using code below instead of `operation.call event`:

```
instance_exec(event, &operation)
```